# Software Floating Point (Howto)

Tags: floating-point

I am wondering if there is any good guide on how software floating point implementations are done - out of curiosity. Anyone have any good references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to look is probably an implementation.  You might find [SoftFloat](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks found the source code of that pretty "easy" to read over.